# Symfony 5 - Emptying elements from a table by user

Tags: symfony

I need to create a button to empty elements from my table "scan" but only for the connected user. scan table :https://prnt.sc/whj3s5
scanner_id and plante_id are both in ManyToOne, scanner_id is the user and plante_id a plant from the table plante.
I already added a button to delete unique element 1 by 1 on my page and it works well. Now i would like to clear all elements with one action but only for the right user. I'm a begginer with Symfony i would need your help please !

my code to delete 1 element 1 by 1 in my controller:

```js
    /**
     * Supprimer une plante dans l'espace personnel utilisateur
     * @Route("/compte/scan/{id}/delete", name="scan_delete")
     * @param Scan $scan
     * @param EntityManager $manager
     * @return Response
     */
    public function delete(Scan $scan, EntityManagerInterface $manager) {
        $manager->remove($scan);
        $manager->flush();

        $this->addFlash("success", "la plante {$scan->getPlante()} a bien été supprimée");

        return $this->redirectToRoute('compte_scan');
    }
```

My User Entity :

```js
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UserRepository::class)
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"email"}, message="Cette adresse mail est déjà utilisée, veuillez en choisir un autre")
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json")
     */
    private $roles = [];

    /**
     * @var string The hashed password
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nom;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $prenom;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $classe;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $pseudo;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Scan::class, mappedBy="scanner")
     */
    private $scans;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->scans = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * A visual identifier that represents this user.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getUsername(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_ELEVE';

        return array_unique($roles);
    }

    public function setRoles(array $roles): self
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getPassword(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        // not needed when using the "bcrypt" algorithm in security.yaml
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // If you store any temporary, sensitive data on the user, clear it here
        // $this->plainPassword = null;
    }

    public function getNom(): ?string
    {
        return $this->nom;
    }

    public function setNom(string $nom): self
    {
        $this->nom = $nom;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPrenom(): ?string
    {
        return $this->prenom;
    }

    public function setPrenom(string $prenom): self
    {
        $this->prenom = $prenom;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getClasse(): ?string
    {
        return $this->classe;
    }

    public function setClasse(string $classe): self
    {
        $this->classe = $classe;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPseudo(): ?string
    {
        return $this->pseudo;
    }

    public function setPseudo(string $pseudo): self
    {
        $this->pseudo = $pseudo;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Scan[]
     */
    public function getScans(): Collection
    {
        return $this->scans;
    }

    public function addScan(Scan $scan): self
    {
        if (!$this->scans->contains($scan)) {
            $this->scans[] = $scan;
            $scan->setScanner($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeScan(Scan $scan): self
    {
        if ($this->scans->removeElement($scan)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($scan->getScanner() === $this) {
                $scan->setScanner(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your `user` entity have a property for the collection of scans ?

Comment: yes in my user entity i've got this :     /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Scan::class, mappedBy="scanner")
     */
    private $scans;

Comment: What's your question about this? Why not gather all entities and remove them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should work fine.

```
/**
 * @Route("/compte/scan/clear", name="scan_clear")
 * @param EntityManagerInterface $entityManager
 * @return Response
 */
public function clear(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager) {
  $user = $this->getUser(); 
  $user->getScans()->clear();
  $entityManager->flush();

  $this->addFlash("success", "Votre liste de plante à été vidé");
  return $this->redirectToRoute('compte_scan');
}
```

If items are not removed from the database when flushing, you might want to loop over the `scans` and explicitely call `$entityManager->remove($scan)`, then `flush`.

```
$user = $this->getUser();
foreach($user->getScans() as $scan) {
  $entityManager->remove($scan);
}
$entityManager->flush();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i tried it, i don't have some errors and i get the flash message on the page but my items are not removed. If i tried to use this -> $entityManager->remove($scan) i've got this error again -> Unable to guess how to get a Doctrine instance from the request information for parameter "scan".

Comment: @Franck I have updated my answer, check it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
$user = $this->getUser(); 
$scans = $user->getScans();

if ($scans) { 
  foreach ($scans as $scan) { 
  $user->removeScan($scan);
  }

  $manager->persist($user);
  $manager->flush();
}
```

this should do.

Edit: refactored

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! i tried to use your code and i've got this error : Unable to guess how to get a Doctrine instance from the request information for parameter "scan".

Comment: I think the error is more with the backend logic. Try to find similar answers related to the error, good old dd($var); will also help.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Putvinskaks Gytis ! i tried this code :

```js
/**
     * Vider les plantes dans l'espace personnel utilisateur
     * @Route("/compte/scan/clear", name="scan_clear")
     * @param Scan $scan
     * @param EntityManager $manager
     * @return Response
     */
    public function clear(Scan $scan, EntityManagerInterface $manager) {

        $user = $this->getUser(); 
        $scans = $user->getScans();

        if ($scans) { 
        foreach ($scans as $scan) { 
        $user->removeScan($scan);
        }

        $manager->persist($user);
        $manager->flush();
        }


        $this->addFlash("success", "Votre liste de plante à été vidé");

        return $this->redirectToRoute('compte_scan');
    }
```

and i got this error : Unable to guess how to get a Doctrine instance from the request information for parameter "scan".